# svg path not drawing for single point on chrome surface

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg, svg-path

I have following svg in HTML, it works fine on all browser on my desktop machine. basically, it shows a point in IE, Chrome, and Firefox and this is how I want, it should display. but chrome on my surface device it's not showing the path, Please tell me how to fix it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<svg height="400" width="400">
 <path stroke="#FF3439" stroke-linecap="round" d="M23.2939901697945,49.74999999999997Z" stroke-width="8"></path>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use a circle element to draw a circle.

Comment: I need only path,

Comment: Well you've established you can't have that so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround to this issue is to make two points out of your single point:

from: d="M23.2939901697945,49.74999999999997Z"
to: d="M23.2939901697945,49.74999999999997Z M23.2939901697945,49.74999999999997Z"

I did reproduce this issue on Mac Chrome 60, this fixed it.

Comment: This is an ugly, and quite possibly unreliable solution.

Comment: It's a workaround, have a better idea? It's a Chrome on Mac where paths with single points are not rendered at all. Can you elaborate on why unreliable?

Comment: Yes. Use a circle as Robert suggested, or if for some reason it really has to be a path, make it a very short line rather than a single move point (or two move points in your case).

Comment: And unreliable because, although it might work on a Mac, you can't guarantee that all browsers on all OSes will render this as desired. Including the OP's Surface device.